# integrating factor y as independent variable

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve a question about integrating factor.In general, $x$ is independent variable but in this question $y$ is being tried as independent variable.

$$ (x + ye^y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 $$

My thought may be wrong
$$ (1-x)\frac{dx}{dy} = ye^y $$

Comment: The second equation is not equivalent to the first. You could multiply both sides by $\frac{dx}{dy}$, however "choosing" which variable is the independent variable does not really matter, since the integration factor, $\mu(x,y)$, should satisfy $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\mu(x,y) (x + y\; e^y)\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(-\mu(x,y)\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rearrangement is incorrect. You have
$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{dy/dx} = x+ye^y, $$
and then you can now integrate in the usual way:
$$ x'-x=ye^y \\
(e^{-y}x)'=y \\
e^{-y}x = \frac{1}{2}y^2+A, $$
and so
$$ x = \frac{1}{2}y^2e^{y}+Ae^{y}, $$
which cannot be solved for $y$ in terms of elementary functions.